# How to get title of from Posts::all() in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get attribute `title` from all of the Posts. Right now I have,
   Posts::all()

I have tried,
   Posts::title and    Posts::title->all()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-pluck):

```
$titles = Posts::all()->pluck('title');
```

Answer (score 2):

Since each Eloquent model serves as a [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries), you may use any query builder method avaible.

So instead of getting all the attributes of the model with `all()` method, and then filtering the resulting collection, you can directly do the query to get only that attribute.

[Retrieving Results](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#retrieving-results)

**Retrieving A List Of Column Values**

> If you would like to retrieve a Collection containing the values of a
>   single column, you may use the pluck method. In this example, we'll
>   retrieve a Collection of post titles:

```
$titles =  Posts::pluck('title');

foreach ($titles as $title) {
    echo $title;
}
```

Or with select:

[Selects](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#selects)

**Specifying A Select Clause**

> You may not always want to select all columns from a database table.
>   Using the select method, you can specify a custom select clause for
>   the query:

```
$posts = Posts::select('title')->get();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo $post->title;
}
```